# Intel MKL 'ddiagemv' multithreaded

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, intel-mkl

I wanted to compare my program (solver for SpMVM, matrix stored in DIA format, written in Fortran) with [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl).

I found the MKL routine `ddiagemv` and it's working perfect in sequential (I'm waaay faster than MKL!). But then, I developped an other version of my program, this time with OpenMP. So I looked around to find a way to make `ddiagemv` multi-threaded, and I don't find anything.

Even though I used `export MKL_NUM_THREADS=4`, `export MKL_DOMAIN_NUM_THREADS="MKL_BLAS=4`, `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`, `export MKL_DYNAMIC="FALSE"` and `export OMP_DYNAMIC="FALSE"`, the time results I get are exactly the same as if I was doing it in sequential.

Are some MKL routines able to be multi-threaded while others are not? If `ddiagemv` can be multi-threaded, how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome, please look around how questions are normally formatted and look at the options and buttons in the question editor (click [edit]). Also read [ask].

Comment: Hope it's better now, thank you for the advice!

Comment: This might help: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor